# Custom Script Extension for Windows :: Running scripts from a local share

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-powershell

Is it possible to Running scripts from a local share inside arm template as it possible via [powershell](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/custom-script-windows#running-scripts-from-a-local-share).

```
$protectedSettings = @{"commandToExecute" = "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File \\filesvr\build\serverUpdate1.ps1"};

Set-AzVMExtension -ResourceGroupName <resourceGroupName> `
    -Location <locationName> `
    -VMName <vmName> `
    -Name "serverUpdate"
    -Publisher "Microsoft.Compute" `
    -ExtensionType "CustomScriptExtension" `
    -TypeHandlerVersion "1.10" `
    -ProtectedSettings $protectedSettings
```

arm:

```
{
  "fileUris": ["https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/privatecontainer/script1.ps1"],
  "commandToExecute": "powershell.exe script1.ps1",
  "managedIdentity" : {}
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to Running scripts from a local share inside arm
> template as it possible via powershell.

***Yes  ,It is possible we can use the PowerShell scripts with ARM template***.

Likewise ,you can check the below sample :

```
"properties": {
    "publisher": "Microsoft.Compute",
    "type": "CustomScriptExtension",
    "typeHandlerVersion": "1.8",
    "autoUpgradeMinorVersion": true,
    "settings": {
        "fileUris": [
            "https://mystorage.blob.core.windows.net/deployment/iis-preConfigureScript.ps1"
        ],
        "commandToExecute": "powershell -ExecutionPolicy Unrestricted -File iis-preConfigureScript.ps1"
    }
}
```

- Need to make sure that we have saved the correct `PowerShell script` in our desired path and passing the `correct url` in settings.

For more information please refer the below links:-

- **SO THREAD|**[***Azure ARM template deployment via CLI failing with .ps1 script extension error***](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46422683/azure-arm-template-deployment-via-cli-failing-with-ps1-script-extension-error?rq=1)
- **MICROSOFT DOCUMENT|** [***Use deployment scripts in ARM templates***](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/templates/deployment-script-template).

Comment: Hi @AjayKumarGhose-MT , thanks for response. But you call script from storage. I want to call from smb file share \\filesvr\build\serverUpdate1.ps1

Comment: Instead of using files uri ,We can share the path of smb file share local location.